# /etc/HOSTNAME on SuSE: short name or FQDN?

Tags: systemd, hostname, opensuse

The file `/etc/HOSTNAME` on SuSE-Linux contains the host name.

Should this be the full qualified domain name, or the short name (without ".")?

Related question: [socket.getfqdn() returns no domain, but socket.gethostname() does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442873/socket-getfqdn-returns-no-domain-but-socket-gethostname-does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that AFAIK  the upper-case `/etc/HOSTNAME` is specific to SuSe systems, but that should be a symbolic link to the a lowercase file name **`/etc/hostname`, which is used by systemd** and should be therefore be present on other distributions as well.

The recommend systemd utility [`hostnamectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html)  distinguishes three different hostnames:

1. the high-level "pretty" hostname which might include all
      kinds of special characters (e.g. "Lennart's Laptop"), which is stored in [`/etc/machine-info`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-info.html)
2. the static hostname which is used to initialize the
      kernel hostname at boot (e.g. "lennarts-laptop"), which is stored in `/etc/hostname`
3. the transient hostname which is a default received from
      network configuration.

The manual page for the hostname configuration file [`man 5 hostname`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostname.html) doesn't really explicitly use the term FQDN but states:

> The `/etc/hostname` file configures the name of the local system that is set during boot using the
>          `sethostname(2)` system call. It should contain a single newline-terminated hostname string.
>   Comments (lines
>          starting with a `#') are ignored.
>   The hostname may be a free-form string up to 64 characters in length;
>          however, it is recommended that it consists **only of 7-bit ASCII lower-case characters and no spaces or dots**,
>          and limits itself to the format allowed for DNS domain name labels, even though this is not a strict
>          requirement.

Where the "*no dots*" is the only hint that the hostname file should only contain the system host name component, without a domain suffix and therefore not a FQDN.

The manual for the `hostname` command is more explicit (`man 1 hostname`) :

> ## THE FQDN
>
> You can't change the FQDN (as returned by `hostname --fqdn`) or the DNS domain name  with this [sic: the `hostname`] command. **The FQDN of the system is the name that the resolver(3) returns for the host name.**

In other words, the hostname is NOT the FQDN.

And then on how to configure the FQDN:

> Technically:  The FQDN is the name gethostbyname(2) returns for the host name returned by gethostname(2).  The DNS domain name is the part after the first dot.
>
> Therefore it depends on the configuration (usually in `/etc/host.conf`) how you can change it. Usually  (if  the hosts file is parsed before DNS or NIS) you can change it in /etc/hosts.

---

BTW: If you do use a FQDN such as `myhost.example.com` as hostname and in `/etc/hostname`, things like `dnsdomain` and `hostname -d` will return empty strings and will NOT split that string at the first dot into a DNS hostname component `myhost` and a  domain name component `example.com`